# wrong tab configuration issue magento with magemonkey

Tags: magento

There has been an error processing your request
Wrong tab configuration.

```
Trace:
#0 [internal function]: Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs->addTab('customer_edit_t...', 'monkey/adminhtm...')
#1 /chroot/home/differe1/differentdrop.com/html/app/code/community/Codnitive/Extifcon/Model/Core/Layout.php(132): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 /chroot/home/differe1/differentdrop.com/html/app/code/community/Codnitive/Extifcon/Model/Core/Layout.php(70): Codnitive_Extifcon_Model_Core_Layout->_runAction(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#3 /chroot/home/differe1/differentdrop.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(214): Codnitive_Extifcon_Model_Core_Layout->_generateAction(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#4 /chroot/home/differe1/differentdrop.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /chroot/home/differe1/differentdrop.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#6 /chroot/home/differe1/differentdrop.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#7 /chroot/home/differe1/differentdrop.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#8 /chroot/home/differe1/differentdrop.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php(98): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#9 /chroot/home/differe1/differentdrop.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_CustomerController->editAction()
#10 /chroot/home/differe1/differentdrop.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#11 /chroot/home/differe1/differentdrop.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 /chroot/home/differe1/differentdrop.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13 /chroot/home/differe1/differentdrop.com/html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 /chroot/home/differe1/differentdrop.com/html/index.php(82): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}
```

Comment: Please use the code {} format and follow the formatting guidelines while asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

For the solution of the Question is :

Please check which others extensions are **Dependent** on the **monkey** extension.

So please **Disable** those extension and check it will working fine without any error.

Comment: Thanks for the quick solutions.